# asp.net mvc ajax.beginform being sent as html.beginform

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax.beginform

I have a partial view from which I would like to display a modal dialog with updated data. User clicking the div would trigger both the display of the modal and the ajax call for the content of the modal to be updated.

```html
<div class="nMmenuItem" >    
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("editItem","nMrestaurant",new { id = Model.ID },
        new AjaxOptions
        {
            HttpMethod = "get",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            UpdateTargetId = "myModalDocument"
        }, new { id = "ajaxEditItem" }))
    {
        <div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" 
             onclick="$('form#ajaxEditItem').submit();">            
            <div class="text-center">
                @Model.name
            </div>
        </div>        
    }
</div>
```

I have a placeholder for the modal inside the parent view:

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" id="myModalDocument">
        @Html.Partial("_editItem", new nMvMmenuItem())
    </div>
</div>
```

But while the controller action is expecting an AjaxResquest, the controller is evaluating Request.IsAjaxRequest() as false.

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> editItem(int? id)
    {
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {                
            return PartialView("_editItem", await db.nMmenuItems.FindAsync(id));
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Which refreshes the whole view and prevents the modal from working.

I am bundling the following scripts in the _Layout.cshtml page:

```
"~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
"~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
"~/Scripts/jquery.unobstrusive*",
"~/Scripts/jquery.validate",
"~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
"~/Scripts/respond.js"
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why not just split the request into it's own method and ditch the IsAjaxRequest check entirely?

Comment: Check the developers console in your browser and see if you have any JS errors. An error will break parsing of other scripts, and `Ajax.BeginForm` is designed to fallback to a standard non-ajax form post.

Comment: @ChrisSearles, you are right I could split the method that way although that will not solve the issue here. I kept it like this to see the false evaluation of IsAjaxRequest as a way to verify if the call is being taken as ajax or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that attaching submit() to the form's onclick event would not perform an ajax request. 
My solution is thus to remove Ajax.SubmitForm and instead deal with the click event in my js:

The updated view looks like this:

```
<div class="nMmenuItem">
<form method="get" action="@Url.Action("editItem","nMrestaurant",new { id = Model.ID })"
      data-nM-ajax="true" data-nM-target="#myModalContent">
    <div>            
        <div class="text-center">
            @Model.name
        </div>            
    </div>
</form>
```

In the js I will bind the form submission to the click event of the parent div:

```
$('.nMmenuItem').click(ajaxFormSubmit);
```

And the function that handles the form submission and opens the resulting modal dialog:

```
var ajaxFormSubmit = function () {        

    var $form = $(this).children('form:first');

    var options = {
        url: $form.attr("action"),
        type: $form.attr("method"),
        data: $form.serialize()
    };

    $.ajax(options).done(function (data) { 
        var $target = $($form.attr("data-nM-target"));                     
        $target.replaceWith(data);
        $("#myModal").modal(dialogOpts);
    });

    return false;

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that you've got the unobtrusive ajax client scripts installed - your bundle pattern looks like it will pick them up if they are there, but I don't believe they are installed in the default project:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax
```

While the Ajax.BeginForm is included in the standard MVC project, the client scripts are not and these are what is responsible for loading the content without refreshing the whole page.

Comment: You are right, the unobstrusive ajax client scripts were not installed. I installed them as you suggested however I must have something else going on here because the solution still doesn't work, i.e. the controller returns the partial view but it is displayed on a blank new page instead of replacing the intended part of the modal.